# How to send custom attribute for chunk file upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm using `blueimp`  file upload plugin but I don't for multiple `files` but I don't know how to send custom attributes. I wanted to send all these custom attribute to **server** with each `chunk` no problem(**how we send  `formData`**). How we send for `formData` similarly, can I send attribute?

```
var formdata = new formData();

formdata.append('filename',currentFile[i]);

formdata.append('filesize',currentFile[i].size);
```

**Note: I wanted to send the data in `chunks`**

Here is a code what I'm trying jsfiddle(in firefox opens perfectly): http://jsfiddle.net/davidchase03/ChJ9B/

**HTML**

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="meter" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="data"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        maxChunkSize: 1048576,
        maxRetries: 3,
        dataType: 'json',
        multipart: false,
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10),
                meter = $('.progress .meter'),
                percent = progress + '%';
            meter.css('width', percent).text(percent);
        },
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').appendTo('.data');
            data.submit();
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            data.context.text('Upload finished.');
        },
        fail: function (e, data) {
            data.context.text('Upload failed.');
            $('.progress').addClass('alert');
            console.warn('Error: ', data);

        }
    }).on('fileuploadchunksend', function (e, data) {
         // if (data.uploadedBytes === 3145728 ) return false;
    }).on('fileuploadchunkdone', function (e, data) {

    });
});
```

**Question**: to make you clear this is what I wanted [How to send custom data to server using jquery-file-uploader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726799/how-to-send-custom-data-to-server-using-jquery-file-uploader)

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send additional custom attribute using headers options.
Example:

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        ...
        headers : {
           customAttribute: 'customValue'
        }
});
```

For Dynamic values, you can use beforeSend callback as explained in the following example

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        ...
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
           xhr.setRequestHeader("customAttribute", someCalculateValueFunction('customValue'));
        }
});
```

Comment: your answer gave me a good clue towards solution, it worked for me, so here is your bounty...........

Comment: Please see this question thanks in advance 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842933/how-to-display-thumnail-or-preview-for-current-file-upload/50850998?noredirect=1#comment88740362_50850998

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    formData: {customAttr: 'value'}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `headers` option to add any custom info

```
maxRetries: 3,
headers: {
   'myname': 'Tarun'
},
dataType: 'json',
```

And then you can see that the headers are sent with every chunk

**Chunk 1**

[image: Chunk 1]

**Chunk 2**

[image: Chunk 2]

Then on server you can extract this information and use the way you like it

Comment: that works perfectly, can't i send same from any of the `callback` let say `fileuploadchunksend:{}`, `add:function{}`.   i need dynamic header please help me with that