# how to display thumnail or preview for current file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm having trouble to display the preview of the `video/image` being **loaded**

Basically I mean to say below code is not **firing** to get `video/image` preview

**It is my [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChJ9B/182/)**

```
.bind('fileuploadprocessalways', function(e, data)
  {
      var canvas = data.files[0].preview;
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
      $("#some-image").css("background-image", 'url(' + dataURL +')');

  })
```

**Question**: please help me to have preview of `video/image` being uploaded

> here is my complete code

**html:**

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="meter" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="data"></div>
<div id="some-image"></div>
```

**javascript:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        maxChunkSize: 1048576,
        maxRetries: 3,
        dataType: 'json',
        multipart: false,
        progressall: function (e, data) {
          //progress
        },
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').appendTo('.data');
            data.submit();
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            data.context.text('Upload finished.');
        },
        fail: function (e, data) {
            data.context.text('Upload failed.');

        }
    }).bind('fileuploadprocessalways', function(e, data)
     {
         var canvas = data.files[0].preview;
         var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
         $("#some-image").css("background-image", 'url(' + dataURL +')');

      })
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a sample how to capture video thumbnail using jQuery. The idea is to have fileupload, then load the video using `video` element set the video currentTime to some random time to get the thumbnail and draw the video using `canvas`.

```js
$(function() {
    var video = $("video");
    var thumbnail = $("canvas");
    var input = $("input[type=file]");
    var ctx = thumbnail.get(0).getContext("2d");
    var duration = 0;
    var img = $("img");

    input.on("change", function(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        // Validate video file type
        if (["video/mp4"].indexOf(file.type) === -1) {
            alert("Only 'MP4' video format allowed.");
            return;
        }
        // Set video source
        video.find("source").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(file));
        // Load the video
        video.get(0).load();
        // Load metadata of the video to get video duration and dimensions
        video.on("loadedmetadata", function(e) {
            duration = video.get(0).duration;
            // Set canvas dimensions same as video dimensions
            thumbnail[0].width = video[0].videoWidth;
            thumbnail[0].height = video[0].videoHeight;
            // Set video current time to get some random image
            video[0].currentTime = Math.ceil(duration / 2);
            // Draw the base-64 encoded image data when the time updates
            video.one("timeupdate", function() {
                ctx.drawImage(video[0], 0, 0, video[0].videoWidth, video[0].videoHeight);
                img.attr("src", thumbnail[0].toDataURL());
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```css
video, canvas {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" accept="video/mp4" />
<video controls>
    <source type="video/mp4">
</video>
<canvas></canvas>
<br/>
<img/>
```

To determines whether the specified media type can be played back you can use this code:

```js
var obj = document.createElement("video");
console.info("video/avi: ", obj.canPlayType("video/avi")  || "no");
console.info("video/mp4: ", obj.canPlayType("video/mp4"));
```

Possible values are:

- `"probably"`: The specified media type appears to be playable.
- `"maybe"`: Cannot tell if the media type is playable without playing it.
- `""`: The specified media type definitely cannot be played.

Comment: @xxmatko,can I do it for images also?  It is not working

Comment: Why not? What file are trying to upload? Could you post it somewhere for me, so I can test it and  probably update the code to it?

Comment: sorry for late reply,here is what im trying http://jsfiddle.net/ChJ9B/187/

Comment: You just need to add the above code to tour solution, this is it http://jsfiddle.net/ChJ9B/189/ and do not forget to mark the answer to help others.

Comment: @xxmatko,  can you please help with your existing code,  support for all video format and images.

Comment: @EaB you just have to edit this `if(["video/mp4"].indexOf(file.type) === -1) {` to include the formats you want

Comment: @xxxmatko, i tried that even though it is not working for .avi files and images

Comment: If we are talking about avi files check your console for this error: "Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: video/avi" probably this the reason why. So just install the required decoder. The code is the same. And as @hungrykoala said, just edit mentioned condition to support the required file types.

Comment: i liked your solution, so awarded bounty................... thanks alot

Comment: @xxmatko,still I'm facing the problem with the `.Avi,.mov,.mpeg` files please help me by creating fiddle

Comment: Well you can check whether the browser can play the specified file format using method `canPlayType`. I've added sample code to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think some thing like this.

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="meter" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="data"></div>
<div id="some-image">
    <img id="uAvata" alt="" />
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#fileupload").change(function(evt) {
        var fileUpload = $(this).get(0).files;
        readURL(this, "#uAvata");
    });
    //Preview image
    function readURL(inputFile, imgId) {
        if (inputFile.files && inputFile.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $(imgId).attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(inputFile.files[0]);
        }
    }
    // Preview video will read video like: @xxxmatko
</script>
```

Comment: This is not very good example because you are reading the whole file content, which can cause this error `"allocation size overflow"`.